# Getting NullPointerException int android.media.MediaPlayer.getDuration()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-mediaplayer

I am getting the nullPointerException using this code in my player Activity
`when i click next button everything works good until 8 or 9 items` from start of recycler view but after that this error comes .
I am creating a music player app everything working was great until i added the `GradientDrawable` to fetch the color from image using palette and applied it to the baground drawable which is having a shape of `gradient` color

```
//nextbuttonclicke method code snippet
  uri1 = Uri.parse(listsong.get(position).getPath());
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), uri1);
        metaDataMethod(uri1);
        sName = listsong.get(position).getTitle();
        song_name.setText(sName);
        if (mediaPlayer == null)
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(PlayerActivity.this, uri1);
        seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration() / 1000);
        PlayerActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(mediaPlayer != null){
                    int mCurrentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / 1000;
                    seekBar.setProgress(mCurrentPosition);
                }
                mHandler.postDelayed(this, 200);
            }
        });
        //MediaMetaData to set album art
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        //this is the end of album art
        pause_play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
        mediaPlayer.start();
```

metadataMethod is below

```
public void metaDataMethod(Uri uri) {
    MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    retriever.setDataSource(uri.toString());
    String totalout = "";
    String totaloutNew = "";
    // get mp3 info
    // convert duration to minute:seconds
    String duration =
            retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
    long dur = Long.parseLong(duration);
    String seconds = String.valueOf((dur % 60000) / 1000);

    String minutes = String.valueOf(dur / 60000);
    totalout = minutes + ":" + seconds;
    totaloutNew = minutes + ":" + "0" + seconds;
    if (seconds.length() == 1) {
        duration_total.setText(totaloutNew);
    }else {
        duration_total.setText(totalout);
    }
    byte[] art = retriever.getEmbeddedPicture();
    final Bitmap image;
    if( art != null ){
        Glide.with(PlayerActivity.this).asBitmap()
                .load(art).into(cover_art);
        image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(art, 0, art.length);
        Palette.from(image).generate(new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGenerated(@Nullable Palette palette) {
                Palette.Swatch vibranSwatch = null;
                Palette.Swatch vibranLigt = null;
                if (palette != null) {
                    vibranSwatch = palette.getVibrantSwatch();
                }
                if (palette != null)
                {
                    vibranLigt = palette.getLightVibrantSwatch();
                }
                //you can generate as many as you want..
                if (vibranSwatch != null)
                {
                    ImageView imgIcon = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                    RelativeLayout mContainer = findViewById(R.id.mContainer);
                    mContainer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.main_bg);
                    imgIcon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gredient_bg);
                    GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.BOTTOM_TOP, new int[]{vibranSwatch.getRgb(),
                            0x00000000});
                    imgIcon.setBackground(gd);

                    GradientDrawable gdContainer = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.BOTTOM_TOP,
                            new int[]{vibranSwatch.getRgb(), vibranSwatch.getRgb()});
                    mContainer.setBackground(gdContainer);
                }
                else if (vibranLigt != null)
                {
                    ImageView imgIcon = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                    RelativeLayout mContainer = findViewById(R.id.mContainer);
                    mContainer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.main_bg);
                    imgIcon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gredient_bg);
                    GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.BOTTOM_TOP, new int[]{vibranLigt.getRgb(),
                            0x00000000});
                    imgIcon.setBackground(gd);
                    GradientDrawable gdContainer = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.BOTTOM_TOP,
                            new int[]{vibranLigt.getRgb(), vibranLigt.getRgb()});
                    mContainer.setBackground(gdContainer);
                }
                else
                {

                }
            }
        });
    }
    else{
        Glide.with(PlayerActivity.this)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(R.drawable.singer)
                .into(cover_art);
    }
    // close object
    retriever.release();
}
```

This is the logcat that i have seen in logcat:

```
04-29 13:43:45.330 7030-7030/com.aman.playmusix E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.aman.playmusix, PID: 7030
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.media.MediaPlayer.getDuration()' on a null object reference
    at com.aman.playmusix.PlayerActivity.nextBtnClicked(PlayerActivity.java:264)
    at com.aman.playmusix.PlayerActivity.access$300(PlayerActivity.java:38)
    at com.aman.playmusix.PlayerActivity$9$1.onClick(PlayerActivity.java:237)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4799)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20042)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:914)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:707)
```

Any Help will be appreciated thank you.

Comment: I wouldn't think it's anything to do with the `GradientDrawable`; directly, anyway. I would guess that you're not releasing `MediaPlayer` instances anywhere before creating new ones like you are in your first snippet. Eventually, `MediaPlayer` runs out of resources, so `create()` fails, and you get that NPE.

Comment: actually i am using `static` ArrayList of Mainactivity to share the file path into the player activity does it leaks memory and thats why i am getting `NPE` ?

Comment: I'm not talking about the paths. I'm talking about the `MediaPlayer` instances themselves. Unless you're calling `mediaPlayer.release()` somewhere, it's running out of resources, and the `MediaPlayer.create()` calls you have in the click method eventually fail.

Comment: Can you give some idea of how to send `object` from fragment to the other activity since i have used static `musicFiles` of MainActivity thats why i think is `NPE` because some songs play and some not may be the reson is i am not able to get the desired `uri` to pass in `MediaPlayer.create()`